# I need to find the print history from my Macbook

Tags: command-line

How can a find a list of documents that have been printed from my mac? I need the completed print jobs only. Can this be done through Terminal?

Answer (score 0):

Open your web browser. In the address bar type in: http://localhost:631
Click on “Jobs” in the menu.
Click “Show Completed Jobs” to display your print history.
Now you see the printer, name of the files that were printed, the user who ordered the print job, document size and details (pages, date).

Comment: Does every Mac keep a list of printed files available? For how long/how far back? And is the list available to any other computers, local or on the internet (Apple maybe)?

Comment: The history is related to the operating system. All OS 10s should support his. I do not think there is a limitation as I can find history of over 1 year. As for LAN access, the history should be available given the user credentials/security policies are valid. On the internet side, its a whole different story (depends on routing, ports, access, etc).